# Interpolating an xarray DataArray for N points and getting a list of N interpolated using dask

Tags: python, dask, python-xarray

Sorry if the title isn't very descriptive, but what I want is the following.

I have a `DataArray` with coordinates `x`, `y` and `t`. I also have a list of `N` coordinates and I'd like to interpolate to get a list of `N` interpolated values. However, I don't quite know how to do that with `xarray` while still taking advantage of the parallelism of dask. Here's an example with random values:

```py
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr

x = np.linspace(0, 1, 10)
datar = xr.DataArray(np.random.randn(10,10,10), dims=('x', 'y', 't'), coords=dict(x=x,
                                                                                  y=x,
                                                                                  t=x))
datar = datar.chunk(dict(t=1))

points = np.array([(0.1, 0.1, 0.1),
                  (0.2, 0.3, 0.3),
                  (0.6, 0.6, 0.6),
                   ])

ivals = []
for point in points:
    x0, y0, t0 = point
    interp_val = datar.interp(x=x0, y=y0, t=t0)
    ivals.append(float(interp_val))
print(ivals)
```

This gives me the correct result of `[-1.7047738779949937, 0.9568015637947849, 0.04437392968785547]`.

Is there any way to achieve the same result but taking advantage of `dask`?

If I naively pass lists to the interpolating function I get a 3 cubed matrix instead:

```py
In [35]: x0s, y0s, t0s = points.T
    ...: print(datar.interp(x=x0s, y=y0s, t=t0s))
    ...: 
<xarray.DataArray (x: 3, y: 3, t: 3)>
dask.array<dask_aware_interpnd, shape=(3, 3, 3), dtype=float64, chunksize=(3, 3, 3), chunktype=numpy.ndarray>
Coordinates:
  * x        (x) float64 0.1 0.2 0.6
  * y        (y) float64 0.1 0.3 0.6
  * t        (t) float64 0.1 0.3 0.6
```

Answer (score 4):

A bit late, but in order to interpolate the way you want, and not having a cube as a result, you should cast your coordinates as `xarray DataArrays` with a fictitious dimension `points`:

```
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr

np.random.seed(1234)

x = np.linspace(0, 1, 10)
datar = xr.DataArray(np.random.randn(10, 10, 10), dims=('x', 'y', 't'), coords=dict(x=x, y=x,  t=x))
datar = datar.chunk(dict(t=1))

points = np.array([(0.1, 0.1, 0.1),
                  (0.2, 0.3, 0.3),
                  (0.6, 0.6, 0.6)])

x = xr.DataArray(points[:, 0], dims="points")
y = xr.DataArray(points[:, 1], dims="points")
t = xr.DataArray(points[:, 2], dims="points")

datar.interp(x=x, y=y, t=t).values
```

It gives you the three values tou want. Two remarks :

- you should time the executions of the two methods, your loop for and my solution, to check if xarray really takes advantage of the multiple points given to `interp`,
- you give the correct values you expect, but they depend on your random data. You should fix the seed before in order to give reproducible examples ;)

Comment: Not sure about the OP, but this was just very helpful to me. What I don't understand: How/why exactly does this work? It sounds only vaguely plausible to me at the moment.

Comment: How does interp works ? Or why the coordinates must be passed into DataArrays ? For the second question, it just prevents xarray from interpolating over the cartesian product of the coordinates inputed.

Comment: that second bit: by which mechanism does assigning the same independent variable, even without values, to the sampling point coordinates, prevent xarray from using the full factorial of the inputs? It clearly works, of course, but I would not have expected it to work. I have a feeling that there may be other useful applications of the same trick.